# element css animation - one element push other element higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to make some animation like this: 
when I hover on the div which contains some image and text which are visible from the beginning, other div which is below the text and the image to "fadeInUp", (this animation is taken from animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). But when I animate div to fadeInUp, text and the image which is above just jump up. I want to make text and image move smoothly up as the div fadeInUp. Here is my code, I hope it will be more understandable:

```
    <div class="service_box_first" onmouseover="service();" onmouseleave="serviceOut();">
         <div class="text-vcenter">
              <div class="index_service_heading" id="naslov">
                   <img src="images/brandingIkona.png"/>
                    <div>BRANDING</div>
              </div>
              <div class="index_service_description animated" id="text">
                   Some text
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>

.service_box_first {
        display: table;
        position: relative;
    }

.text-vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.index_service_description {
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Classes .service_box_first and .text-vcenter are used to vertically center content inside the div with .text-vcenter class. Functions service() and serviceOut() are used to animate the div with text. Animation is here:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            height: 0px;
          }

          100% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
              height: 150px;
          }
        }

        @keyframes fadeInUp {


   0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    .fadeInUp {
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
      animation-name: fadeInUp;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the JavaScript involved too, or better, use this fiddle to show us your problem https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/fb1masxe/

Comment: Is this the desired outcome? https://jsfiddle.net/4etajbcw/3/